# How to get object with largest number of related objects in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have model A(Post):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

and model B(Like):

```
class Like(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How would I retrieve the Post object with the largest number of likes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate the `Post` object with the number of likes, and then get the [**`.earliest()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#earliest) when we order the number of likes in descending order:

```
from django.db.models import Count

most_liked_post = Post.objects.annotate(
    num_likes=Count('like')
).earliest('-num_likes')
```

Comment: Ok will I have to import Count() from somewhere?

Comment: And isn't .earliest() to find the earliest created objects?

Comment: @svoruganti: no. In fact a database does not keep track on *when* you created a record. You can do that by adding a timestamp or something. But `.earliest(...)` basically orders by the field(s) provided, and returns the *first* one.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, but where would I get the Count() imported from?

Comment: @svoruganti: edit the answer: `from django.db.models import Count`.

Comment: Hi, how could this query be edited to return the first 10 instead of the first object?

Comment: @svoruganti: instead of `.earliest()`, `.order_by('-num_likes')[:10]`.